# Turn an LED on or off in AT Mega-1284P Xplained

Tags: avr, led

I am a beginner in AT Mega-1284P Xplained.

I want to turn an LED on and then off (say, LED0) after some specified time in AT Mega 1284P Xplained board from ATMEL. To my surprise, I found no official documentation for this rudimentary task but several different function calls - all of which failed compilation - searching on the web.

Please mention the API call as well as the header file that needs to be included for this. I am using AVR Studio 6.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume a led is connected to pin 0 at port b on the AtMega1284P. The following program should make the led blink.

```
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

int main() {
  // Set the pin 0 at port B as output
  DDRB |= (1<<PB0);

  while(1) {    
    // Turn led on by setting corresponding bit high in the PORTB register.
    PORTB |= (1<<PB0);

    _delay_ms(500);

    // Turn led off by setting corresponding bit low in the PORTB register.
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0);

    _delay_ms(500);

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @netbear,thanks for your reply. I am using the discovery board 'AT Mega-1284P Xplained' and the assumption that 'a led is connected to pin 0 at port b on the AtMega1284P' is not in my hand. This is one of the reasons I mentioned the name of the board on the subject line.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I found Atmel had an example code that covered a bunch of sensors and other peripheral components including LEDs for Mega-1284P. The links are [link](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/mega.applications.mega_1284p_xplained.example/html/group__mega__1284p__xplained__group.html#application_description) and [link](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/mega.applications.mega_1284p_xplained.example/html/mega__1284p__xplained__example_8c_source.html). Besides, very hard to find locations (they did not show up on web searches), the websites are _very_slow. Atmel, are you listening?